# Unreads Sidebar Setting not visible in Mattermost 4.7

Tags: mattermost

We just upgraded to Mattermost 4.7 but there is no "Unreads" Sidebar Setting in the front-end. I can find it in the Mattermost peer-to-peer channel, so I know where it should be, but in our installation the feature is not visible.

Does anyone know what we are missing? We are not using the Enterprise version, but according to the documentation this should be in the community edition.

https://docs.mattermost.com/help/settings/account-settings.html?highlight=unreads#group-unreads-channels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is an experimental feature, you need to enable it in your `config.json` file before the setting will become available in individual users' Account Settings. To do this, in the `ServiceSettings` block of `config.json` you should set `ExperimentalGroupUnreadChannels` to either `default_on` or `default_off` (to have it be enabled or disabled by default respectively).

Comment: thanks. Thats it. There is already a ticket for adapting the documentation accordingly.